# why hg clone taking too long from openjdk url

Tags: java, mercurial, openjdk-11

I have to build **jdk 11** from source.

I am trying to clone **jdk11u** source repo using below command. Its been more than 5 hours and it is still running. I am using release tag ***jdk-11.0.12+6*** for which I want to fetch source code.

Is this URL correct? what am I missing here.

**command :**

```
$ hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk11u -r jdk-11.0.12+6 /home/jack/hgclone/
```

`/home/jack/hgclone/` is local repo where I want to clone code.

Comment: I am able to clone jdk8u repo using below command :
'hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u'